# iPhone locked for ransom: how to recover if it's offline?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to help a friend who got her iPhone locked for ransom through the "I lost my iPhone" feature.
The screen is locked and says "Dlya polucheniya parolya, napishite na e-mail: helpicloud3@gmail.com".
I got her to change her password and use the "sign out of all browsers" option on AppleID so now she should be the only one with access to it.
I thought that was over, but when she accessed the "Lost my iPhone" page to unlock the phone it said "Device is offline". We checked and the iPhone seems to have WiFi off and says "SIM locked" in the status bar, upper left.

I looked around for a solution, but found nothing. I searched the ransom message over google (https://www.google.it/search?q=Dlya+polucheniya+parolya%2C+napishite+na+e-mail:+helpicloud3%40gmail.com) and found 3 sites: two in Russian (still have to check them) and one in English (http://kilishek.com/index.php/2016/05/14/friday-13-my-apple-id-was-hacked/), where someone describes the same exact ransom happening the same exact day, but he had no problem in recovering the iPhone.

Can someone help me?

Edit:
Problem solved: the iPhone's SIM had the PIN activated and this prevented it from connecting to the cloud.

Comment: Contact Apple immediately - https://getsupport.apple.com

Comment: I agree with @Tetsujin; you shouldn't spend time here waiting for possible answers, you need to contact Apple (and possibly the police).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this iPhone model has a SIM card, try to put it to another phone/iPhone and try to disable SIM Pin.

On iPhone:
Settings -> Phone -> SIM PIN -> disable

Then put this SIM again to your friend's iPhone and reboot it. After restart, iPhone should automatically log in to cellular network and you should be able to disable  the lost mode using iCloud page.

Maybe your friend should consider using two factor authentication to enable additional protection to iCloud account:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out by myself, but you are completely right. The SIM had a PIN and that was why it could not connect. Removing the PIN via another phone solved the problem: I disabled the lock through the Web.

Answer (score 5):

## Contact Apple. *Immediately.*

1. This is probably a security breach of your friend's iCloud account. In order to lock your friend's iPhone, his/her iCloud password is required.
2. This could either mean that there is a security flaw within iCloud that is not known by Apple and has been exploited or that your friend might have leaked their credentials to a phishing scam.

You can contact Apple support right here:
https://getsupport.apple.com

Alternatively, because your friend's phone is being held for *ransom*, you might want to contact the local police and report a case.

*You may want to try [SvenS's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238382/162909) and see if that disables the SIM lock, though I doubt it is the cause of the phone being locked.*

Comment: +1 for recommending a police report. Large criminal organizations often use small crimes such as these to fund operations, and reporting these incidents is helpful in apprehending these groups.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I solved the issue like in SvenS answer. I contacted Apple and am now waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this iPhone model has a SIM card, try to put it to another phone/iPhone and try to disable SIM Pin.

On iPhone: Settings -> Phone -> SIM PIN -> disable

Then put this SIM again to your friend's iPhone and reboot it. After restart, iPhone should automatically log in to cellular network and you should be able to disable the lost mode using iCloud page.

Maybe your friend should consider using two factor authentication to enable additional protection to iCloud account: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915

There is no sim card installed on my iPad. What can I do? Thanks guys!

Comment: **'_There is no sim card installed on my iPad. What can I do? Thanks guys!_'** Please open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

### From [Apple Support](http://getsupport.apple.com):

> If you have lost or found an Apple product, please contact your local law enforcement agency to report it.

## Basically, call the police.

*Screenshot:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So this happened to me today. On my phone, I had a passcode so I was able to unlock it right away but on my kids iPads that are linked, there wasn't a passcode. I called apple and they helped me with hooking the iPad up to iTunes on my computer and doing a restore. So definitely call apple and they will help. It took an hour so that sucked but at least it worked.

Answer (score 0):

happened to me today.. woke up this morning to a message in Russian saying that my iphone had be held for ransom.. I went into work and the IT guy helped me with hooking the phone up to iTunes and doing a factory reset... Call apple right away when this happens especially if you have credit or debit card info linked to your phone